# Is this how to implement ascending sort when the comparator sorts descending?

Tags: java, comparator

Is this how to implement ascending sort when the comparator sorts descending?

```
// Sorts the emails alphabetically by subject in ascending order.
public void sortBySubjectAscending()
{
Collections.sort(emails, Collections.reverseOrder(new Email.SubjectDescendingComparator()));
}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to submit an answer that just says "Yes."...

Comment: Have you tried it with a small test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. If you reverse a descending comparator, you get an ascending comparator.

To break it down, this is what you are doing:

```
Comparator ascending = Collections.reverseOrder(new Email.SubjectDescendingComparator());
Collections.sort(emails, ascending);
```

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of being "that StackOverflow guy"...... :)

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29

> public static Comparator reverseOrder()
>
> Returns a comparator that imposes the reverse of the natural ordering >  on a collection of objects that implement the Comparable
>   interface. (The natural ordering is the ordering imposed by the
>   objects' own compareTo method.) This enables a simple idiom for
>   sorting (or maintaining) collections (or arrays) of objects that
>   implement the Comparable interface in reverse-natural-order.

It's educational to think about how you would implement this yourself, compareTo returns an int, all you need to do is invert the result....

Answer (score 0):

yes this is a good solution

personally I'd have a comparator be a static member so you don't need to reinitialize it each time you want to sort and have Email also be able to give a ascendingComparator

```
public class Email{

    private static class SubjectDescendingComparator implements Comparable<Email>{
        //...
    }

    private static final Comparable<Email> subjectDescendingComparator =new SubjectDescendingComparator();
    private static final Comparable<Email> subjectAcendingComparator = Collections.reverseOrder(subjectDescendingComparator);


    public static Comparable<Email> getDecendingSubjectComparator{
        return subjectDescendingComparator;
    }


    public static Comparable<Email> getAcendingSubjectComparator{
        return subjectAcendingComparator;
    }


}
```

Comment: How would I change the method to make it static?

Comment: @nnn check my edit, but adding static to the signature will suffice